# Switching to open folders on a Mac

Tags: macos, switch, tasks

How do I easily switch to an open folder on a Mac?

In Windows, which I'm used to using, I can see all my opened folders in my vertical taskbar, all I need to do to switch to another window is click on the folder in the task bar.

There's no taskbar on a Mac, and when I have a lot of folders opened, ie. lots of Finder windows, how can I switch between them?

The way I'm doing it is, I put expose on an active corner and switch that way. However that's still damn hard, because first I have to bring up expose, and then find my window. The folders are placed in a random position between opened apps, the folders are not in a list, and on a big screen I have to scan the whole screen in order to find the one I want... etc.

Is it really this hard just to switch to a different folder on a Mac?

Is there a taskbar solution on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Finder:**

Finder's built-in keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick). This will cycle through your open windows. Alternatively there is the Window menu (Thanks @David Rouse)

**Using Exposé:**

Depending on the keyboard you have you have a couple options. These are also modified in the Exposé preference pane in System Preferences. You can see a picture of the newer style keyboard layout at [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/283117/imac-ultra+thin-metal-keyboard-images-may-show-dashboard-media-icons).

- "Normal"/Older style Apple keyboards without the Exposé and Dashboard symbols on <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd>:

  - <kbd>F9</kbd> will show all windows available from any application.
  - <kbd>F10</kbd> will show all the windows available from the frontmost application only.
  - <kbd>F11</kbd> will show your Desktop.
- Newer style Apple keyboards with the Exposé and Dashboard symbols on <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd>

  - <kbd>F3</kbd> will show all windows available from any application
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> will show all windows available from the frontmost application only.
  - <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> will show your Desktop
  - <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> will bring up the Exposé preference pane.
- Or just set your hot corner action to "Application Windows" instead of "All Windows" if you prefer to mouse.

**Using Witch:**

If you're looking for something like the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher but for windows instead of applications check out [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/). Version 3.0 was just released.

Comment: Just a note, cmd-` works for every Mac application to cycle through windows, not just the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Snow Leopard, click-and-hold on the finder icon in the taskbar.  It will Expose all of, and only, your finder windows.  This works for any task, BTW.

Comment: Great tip, is there any way to get the expose to happen faster?

Comment: ALso is there any way to get expose to behave like a list, rather than a preview, so I don't have to drag my eyes across the full screen to see the items.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do either.

Comment: @charles if Finder is focused, you can Ctrl+F3 to Expose only the Finder. It works with whatever app is focused.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but:

1) The Finder has a "Window" menu and a list by name of all of your open Finder windows will appear at the bottom of the menu. Unfortunately, two clicks instead of one -- but the names of the folders are less likely to be truncated.

2) If you have several folders that you normally switch between -- drag the folders to the Finder's sidebar under "Places." Then you can click to switch between folders (while only keeping one window open), drag items between folders, etc. A nice side benefit is that these folders will also appear in open and save dialog boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit <kbd>Apple</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick/accent and tilde key) to switch between that applications windows.

To switch between applications you can hit <kbd>Apple</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> which will cycle through applications.

In response to your edit, there isn't a reason I can think of to ever want a task bar like Windows. Learn to use your keyboard and you'll never even need to click on applications in the dock.

Comment: Thanks, great tip, still, what if you're not on a folder. Also toggling through folders is still not quite ideal, or very speedy at all.

Comment: What do you mean, not on a folder? You mean on Finder? Updated answer.

Comment: @josh: i think you mean "backtick"; "accent" might be a proper term too so i left both in.  the kbd tags make it a little easier to see.

Comment: I use apple tab and alt tab all the time. But seriously you're not suggesting to go from chrome to a specific finder window I need to first apple tab to it and then apple tilde to the folder whereas I could just click on one item on a taskbar?

Comment: If you have so many Finder folders open you can't just Apple+Tab to it then the task bar isn't going to help anyways. I'm 100% faster then any other mouse tied Windows user. Not to sound condescending, but the keyboard is the way to go on this.

Comment: Have you ever seen a taskbar? It blows my mind to hear you say that it does not help. Of course I can just apple tab to it, it's just that then I would have to apple tilde to the correct folder, much, much slower.

Comment: What do you mean, have I ever seen the taskbar. You mean the tiny strip that's overflowing with windows? I have ten windows open right now, that would completely crowd the taskbar. Again, to reiterate, if you become proficient with the keyboard you won't even have to use the taskbar.

Comment: That's why I have a vertical taskbar, I can fit like 20 folders in it, not that I do, but I mean, have fun tilding through 10 folders instead of just clicking once. BTW, I *don't click on applications in the dock.

Comment: If there ever was a reason to have ten finder windows open I might.